# ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null ( CodeIgniter 4 )

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, routes, codeigniter-4

When I go to 'create_datapegawai' views, it goes to detail_datapegawai.

[image]

So, my routes for *detail_pegawai* is:

```
$routes->get('/admin/(:segment)', 'Admin::detail_pegawai/$1');
$routes->get('/admin/create_datapegawai', 'Admin::create_pegawai');
```

when i put my *create_datapegawai* routes below *detail_pegawai* it said Error. but, when i put my *create_datapegawai* above *detail_pegawai* it goes well.

My question is, how to make the routes works well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Routes are registered in the routing table in the order in which they
> are defined. This means that when a URI is accessed, the first
> matching route will be executed.
> Document URL: [Route Priority](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=route)

If you define route same as:

```
$routes->get('/admin/(:segment)', 'Admin::detail_pegawai/$1');
$routes->get('/admin/create_datapegawai', 'Admin::create_pegawai');
```

URL: /admin/create_datapegawai matched with route '/admin/(:segment)'

So, put specific route first. In your case, put create_datapegawai above detail_pegawai works well.

```
$routes->get('/admin/create_datapegawai', 'Admin::create_pegawai');
$routes->get('/admin/(:segment)', 'Admin::detail_pegawai/$1');
```